# Multimap to JSON

Tags: java, json, multimap

I have a very huge Multimap. I an trying to convert this Multimap to JSONArray as a key value. But i am getting the following Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:237)
at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:112)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:544)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:404)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.write(TypeAdapters.java:353)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.write(TypeAdapters.java:337)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:209)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:146)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:105)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:105)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:209)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:146)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:586)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:565)
```

I have tried :

```
Multimap<String,JSONArray > multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(multiMap.asMap());
```

While searching for the issue i came to know about the concept of Streaming and trid to appy it. by following:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

But that example shows a List but not a Multimap as a keyvalue pair. Can anyone please suggest how can i convert this multimap to a JSONArray.

Note: I have tried to increase the heap in eclipse to 2048 but still i have the same issue.

I am still facing the same issue. Can anyone please suggest? :(

Comment: Any Suggestions anyone please?

Answer (score 0):

You increase the eclipse heap or your application heap ? You need to increase your application heap!

With streaming, you write the json somewhere for instance a file :

```
OutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream("myFile.json");
gson.toJson(yourObject, outputStream);
```